# ServiceStack Custom Registration

Tags: c#, asp.net, servicestack

I'm working with ServiceStack 4.0.33.

I'm trying to sort out how to add some custom validation around the RegisterService().

Basically what I need to do is validate a one-time-use beta key prior to permitting registration. If the key is good, the key will be flagged as consumed after registration succeeds.  I started by trying to implement a custom RegistrationValidator but the default Register dto that service stack uses obviously doesn't have a suitable property for me to validate.

I've tried creating a custom class that inherits from the Register DTO, but I can't work out how to tell the RegistrationService, or the RegistrationValidator to work against it.

I've also looked at creating a class that inherits from RegistrationService but there is nothing to override.

Basically all that appears to be provided for registration is 
Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature());

I suspect I'm attacking this from the wrong direction entirely. Either that or there truly is no flexibility around the registration mechanism. could use some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create a custom validator that inherits the existing `RegistrationValidator` to inherit the existing validation, otherwise you can inherit `AbstractValidator<Register>` to overwrite it completely with your own impl, e.g:

```
public class CustomRegistrationValidator : RegistrationValidator
{
    public CustomRegistrationValidator()
    {
        RuleSet(ApplyTo.Post, () =>
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.UserName).Must(x => false)
                .WithMessage("CustomRegistrationValidator is fired");
        });
    }
}
```

To register a validator, you can just register it like any dependency, e.g:

```
container.RegisterAs<CustomRegistrationValidator, IValidator<Register>>();
```

which the Registration Service just resolves from the IOC to use it:

```
public class RegisterService<TUserAuth> : Service
{
    public IValidator<Register> RegistrationValidator { get; set; }
    //...
}
```